# Kotlin method generic type verification

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write a method that takes a KProperty1 and a object of R like so

```
inline fun <T: Any, R: Any> List<T>.test(prop1: KProperty1<T, R>, prop2: R): List<T>
```

except I'm not getting type checking on the prop2. Is there any way to ensure that prop2 is of type R?

Here is a more complete example

```
class Foo

class Bar(val foo: Foo)

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
    val list = listOf(Bar(Foo()))
    list.test(Bar::foo, Foo()) // This should work
    list.test(Bar::foo, "") // I want this to be a type error since a string is not a Foo
}

inline fun <T: Any, R: Any> List<T>.test(prop1: KProperty1<T, R>, prop2: R): List<T> {
    println(prop1.invoke(this.first())::class == prop2::class)
    return listOf()
}
```

Comment: Provide more details please. You can't pass object of not R type as prop2 param.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict `R` to children of `Foo` then provide upper bound constraint:

```
inline fun <T: Any, R: Foo> List<T>.test(prop1: KProperty1<T, R>, prop2: R): List<T> {
    println(prop1.invoke(this.first())::class == prop2::class)
    return listOf()
}
```